# Derive the Probability Generating Function for a Series of Bernoulli Trials

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, generating-functions

I am trying to find the PGF with the following definition:
$$ F(z) = <z^n> = E[z^n] = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}P_nz^n $$
Considering a discrete probability distribution given by $P_n = p(1-p)^n$ for $(n=0,1,2,...)$.

My attempt:
$$ F(z) = <z^n> = E[z^n] = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}p(1-p)^nz^n $$
$$ = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}p[(1-p)z]^n $$
which is just a geometric series so you can simplify as
$$ F(z) =\frac{p}{1-qz} $$
where $q=1-p$. I don't know where I went wrong but just looking around online I think the PGF for a Bernoulli Trial type distribution should be:
$$ PGF = q+pz $$
Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Your $p_n$ formula makes it clear your random variable is a geometric rv, which is not the same thing as a Bernoulli distribution.  Both have $p$ and $q$ in their formulas, but they are not the same thing.

Comment: If you have only one Bernoulli random variable $X$, then $\mathbb E[z^X]=q+pz$. In your case you are considering a geometric distribution.

Comment: so then is this correct? Shouldn't it represent a Binomial Distribution if it is successive Bernoulli trials